# Can you create an age structure of population, if the age was established using multiple different methods?

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, coefficient-of-determination

I want to analyse a age structure of my sample. However, I was not given the ages themselves and instead had to establish them using multiple methods with various coefficients of determination (not every method could be used on every single analysed sample), with some of the methods being run twice to check its replicability.
Because of that, for each individual I have various different estimated ages from different methods, as can be seen on the following picture:

[image: table with five different measurements of age from one individual with coefficient of determination for each corresponding method]

Because of the multiple values, I am not sure how to create the age structure, as some of the results show over twenty years of possible range of age for one person. And I am pretty sure you cannot just average the ages, as those are different methods with different coefficients of determination.

Could anyone give me an advice on this? Would you attempt to create one age estimation from all of the methods, create overlapping categories or go at it in a completely different way?

Comment: You might take either a mean or a median of the estimates, with either equal weights or weights proportional to the $R^2$ of the methods. Either median would give the Star value of 42.55 in this case; either mean would be lower. Then you can test which approach works best for your application; I’m not sure there’s a lot of theory to select one approach.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "age structure"?  Also, what is R^2 in this case?

Comment: I am analyzing the demographic characteristic of a middle ages graveyard. Ive used the following methods to establish the age, with the +- being confidence intervals set by the methods and r2 being the coefficient of determination aka squared Pearson (also set by the methods). And basically, I want to create a graph showing the age structure of the graveyard - x people were of age 20-25, x of 30-35, but for that I need to have one specific age per person.